# Extension of Measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider the following steps of extension of a measure:

(1) Define $\mathbb{P}$, a probability measure on $F$, a field of subsets of a set $\Omega$.

(2) First extension of $\mathbb{P}$ goes as follows. Establish $G$, which is a collection of all limits of increasing sequence of sets in $F$. This is the collection of all countable unions of sets in $F$. Define $\mu$ on $G$, where $\mu=\mathbb{P}$ on $F$.

(3) Now, we try to extend $\mu$ to the class of all subsets of $\Omega$.

My question: in (3), why is it that the $\mu$ will not be countably additive on all subsets but only on a smaller $\sigma$-field? The book defines the outer measure $\mu^*$ on $\Omega$ after (3) due to this reason. AND THEN, the author identifies a $\sigma$-field on which the outer measure $\mu^*$ is countably additive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be answered with an example.

Take for instance $\Omega=[0,1]$  and $P=m^*$ Lebesgue outer measure.

Take $V\subseteq [0,1]$ a non measurable set.

Then $m^*$ defined on the powerset of $[0,1]$ is not even finitely additive.

This is because $m^*(V)+m^*([0,1] \setminus V)>m^*(([0,1] \setminus V) \cup V)$

Comment: Hi Marios, thanks for the response. I re-read what the author states. Is this because the sets are not measurable? So, the act of "looking only on a smaller sigma field" is analogous to looking only measurable sets? Is this why we motivate to define what is called outer measure, in order to concretely narrow down the sets that could be consistently defined as "measurable"?

Comment: Just by this example,you can see that you cannot  always construct a measure on a powerset..since you can find very pathological examples of sets that cannot be measured,like $V$ for instance.

Comment: @FrankSwanton  ..yes thats why we do this...an outer measure is not sigma additive always..if you can find an appropriate class of sets then it can become a measure..

Comment: So do we have this relationship then? $\Omega\subset F\subset\sigma(F)\subset 2^{\Omega}$?

Comment: In this example yes..

Comment: great. I think it is more clear now! thanks.